# On hardware back button check whether any modal is present and dismiss the modal

Tags: angular, ionic4

Ionic v4 - On hardware back button I have to check whether any modal is present. If any modal is present then close that modal. If no modal is present then go one page back

I have used below line of code

**Code:**

```
    private backButtonEvent() {
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
        debugger;
        try {
            let activeModal = await this.modalCtrl.getTop();
            debugger;
            if(activeModal) {
                activeModal.dismiss();
                return;
            }
        } catch(ex) { console.log(ex); }
        this.routerOutlet.forEach((ro: IonRouterOutlet) => {
            if (this.router.url === '/login' || this.router.url === '/home') {
                if (this.router.url === '/home') {
                    this.common.confirmShow('Exit', 'Do you want to exit the app ?\r\nYou will be logged out after closing the app').then(d => {
                        if (d == 1) {
                            navigator['app'].exitApp();
                        }
                    }).catch(e => { console.log(e); });    
                } else if (this.router.url === '/login') {
                    navigator['app'].exitApp();
                }
            }
            else if (ro && ro.canGoBack()) {
                ro.pop();
            }
        });
    });        
}
```

Here, it always satisfies the activeModal true

Comment: Subscribe to an observable which looks for the hardware based 'back button' and then close modal or go back to browser's previous page

Comment: Everything keeping same, I have used "this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, async () => {", works very well